# Counting the number of letters in a .txt file in Pascal

Tags: beginner, pascal

I wrote this program that counts the number of letters in random.txt file in the Pascal programming language.
It doesn't matter if the letters are capitalized. Other characters are ignored. When it finishes it writes every letter in a single line and then after it the number of appearences of that letter in the text file.

```
program letters;
var 
random:text;
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1:integer;

procedure counting(random:text; var a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1:integer);
var 
c:char;
begin
a1:=0;
b1:=0;
c1:=0;
d1:=0;
e1:=0;
f1:=0;
g1:=0;
h1:=0;
i1:=0;
j1:=0;
k1:=0;
l1:=0;
m1:=0;
n1:=0;
o1:=0;
p1:=0;
q1:=0;
r1:=0;
s1:=0;
t1:=0;
u1:=0;
v1:=0;
w1:=0;
x1:=0;
y1:=0;
z1:=0;
while not eof(random) do
while not eoln do
begin
if (c='A') or (c='a') then a1:=a1+1;
if (c='B') or (c='b') then b1:=b1+1;
if (c='C') or (c='c') then c1:=c1+1;
if (c='D') or (c='d') then d1:=d1+1;
if (c='E') or (c='e') then e1:=e1+1;
if (c='F') or (c='f') then f1:=f1+1;
if (c='G') or (c='g') then g1:=g1+1;
if (c='H') or (c='h') then h1:=h1+1;
if (c='I') or (c='i') then i1:=i1+1;
if (c='J') or (c='j') then j1:=j1+1;
if (c='K') or (c='k') then k1:=k1+1;
if (c='L') or (c='l') then l1:=l1+1;
if (c='M') or (c='m') then m1:=m1+1;
if (c='N') or (c='n') then n1:=n1+1;
if (c='O') or (c='o') then o1:=o1+1;
if (c='P') or (c='p') then p1:=p1+1;
if (c='Q') or (c='q') then q1:=q1+1;
if (c='R') or (c='r') then r1:=r1+1;
if (c='S') or (c='s') then s1:=s1+1;
if (c='T') or (c='t') then t1:=t1+1;
if (c='U') or (c='u') then u1:=u1+1;
if (c='V') or (c='v') then v1:=v1+1;
if (c='W') or (c='w') then w1:=w1+1;
if (c='X') or (c='x') then x1:=x1+1;
if (c='Y') or (c='y') then y1:=y1+1;
if (c='Z') or (c='z') then z1:=z1+1;
end;
close(random);
end;

procedure result(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1:integer);
begin
writeln('A','',a1);
writeln('B','',b1);
writeln('C','',c1);
writeln('D','',d1);
writeln('E','',e1);
writeln('F','',f1);
writeln('G','',g1);
writeln('H','',h1);
writeln('I','',i1);
writeln('J','',j1);
writeln('K','',k1);
writeln('L','',l1);
writeln('M','',m1);
writeln('N','',n1);
writeln('O','',o1);
writeln('P','',p1);
writeln('Q','',q1);
writeln('R','',r1);
writeln('S','',s1);
writeln('T','',t1);
writeln('U','',u1);
writeln('V','',v1);
writeln('W','',w1);
writeln('X','',x1);
writeln('Y','',y1);
writeln('Z','',z1);
end;

begin
    assign(random,'random.txt');
    reset(random);
    counting(random,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1);
    result(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1);
    readln();
end.
```

I'm a beginner and I suppose this can be done a lot better and simpler without having to use 26 variables. How could I improve my code to make it work better? Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Did you consider to use an array? You will drop 80% of your code

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know how to use it in this situation. Could you tip me how? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: I wrote my last line in pascal almost 25 years ago, I do not think I will write decent code. Outline: keep an array of 24 elements. Check if each char is `c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z'` and in case subtract `'A'` to get index of  array. Increment item at that index by 1. If your library does not have a `tolower()` function then repeat for `a`.  Then use proper indentation and meaningful names (`random` as parameter name? Why?)

Comment: " in case subtract 'A' to get index of array." - I didn't quite get this part. Regarding random as name, it's because I'm not a native english speaker, I had a more meaningful name in my language but I changed it so I could post it here. @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Pascal but in your case you need few lines more because calculation is case insensitive and you want to consider only Latin characters (subtract A means _subtract its ASCII value, 65_)

Answer (score 2):

- Declaring 26 individual counter variables:
  Now this is generally considered bad style.
  These 26 variables fulfill a common purpose, yet they are completely independent from each other.
  A simple solution would at least use

  ```pascal
  var
      chart: array[char] of integer;
  ```

  Now this is quite wasteful, because the range `chr(0)..maxChar` which we’re using for this array’s first and only dimension contains lots of unused entries.
  Specifically, both `chart['A']` and `chart['a']` coexist.
  We can remediate this situation and declare an `array` containing only 26 `integer` values, or we can leave this as is and simply print `chart['A'] + chart['a']` in our final printing procedure.
- ```pascal
  procedure counting(random:text; […]
  ```

  Parameters of the data type `file of …` (including parameters of the data type `text`) always must be passed as `var` parameters.
  Any decent compiler will reject your code.
- ```pascal
  var 
  random:text;
  a1,…,z1:integer
  procedure counting(random:text; var a1,…,z1:integer);
  […]
  procedure result(a1,…,z1:integer);
  ```

  Now this shows that you have not understood the concept of scopes.
  Because you have declared your variables *before* the definitions of `counting` and `result`, you can access them directly in `counting` and `result`.
  There is no need to pass all variables in parameters.
  The entire parameter list could be left out and your `program` would still work (you, of course, have to adjust the calls below accordingly).

  Generally speaking, global variables, i. e. the declaration of variables before any routines, is considered bad.
  I would simply move the `var`-section you have down *below* the procedures, right before the program’s “main” `begin … end`.
- ```pascal
  a1:=0;
  …
  z1:=0;
  ```

  If you had an Extended Pascal (ISO standard 10206) compliant compiler, you could specify an initial value at the variable declaration, like so:

  ```pascal
  var
      a1, b1, c1: integer value 0;
  ```
- You do not read anything in the reading loop:

  ```pascal
  while not {EOF / EOLn respectively} do
  […]
  end;
  ```

  Is an infinite loop, because your “reading cursor” remains at the same position.
  There is no `read(random, c)`.
  This also means your `c` remains uninitialized.
  You’re reading an uninitialized value which is very bad.
- In Pascal the expression

  ```pascal
  (c='A') or (c='a')
  ```

  is usually written as

  ```pascal
  c in ['A', 'a']
  ```
- Since any `Boolean` expression can be converted into an `integer` using `ord`, you could rephrase your line(s)

  ```pascal
  if (c='A') or (c='a') then a1:=a1+1;
  ```

  to

  ```pascal
  a1 := a1 + ord(c in ['A', 'a']);
  ```

  This will add `0` or `1` to `a1`.
  Some people find this more elegant instead of single-line `if … then`s.
- ```pascal
  writeln('A','',a1);
  ```

  Writing an empty string (`''`) has no effect.
  Maybe you wanted append a minimum width specifier to create a tabular look?

  ```pascal
  writeLn('A', '':4, a1);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

Comment: @TobySpeight Unfortunately there are very few [tag:Pascal] code review requests. It’s already weird to respond to a five year old request. Frankly I think Plexus (the requester) would not write such code today, so he does not need any feedback (anymore).

Comment: There are also few Pascal answerers, which makes your contribution the more welcome!  Answering old questions is fine, as we aim to help all programmers improve their code (not just the askers), so please do continue doing that.  I find that answering (in the languages I know - it's over 30 years since I touched any Pascal) also improves my own skills, too.